# AngularJS: Value in controller generated by service isn't working?

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="NumCtrl as ctrl">
<input type="text" id="textbox" ng-model="ctrl.num">
    <h1>{{ctrl.num}}</h1>

    <h3>Factorial</h3>
    <p>{{ctrl.showfactorial}}</p>
```

Controller:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('NumCtrl', NumCtrl)

function NumCtrl(mathify) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.showfactorial = mathify.factorial(ctrl.num);
}
```

Service:

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.service('mathify', mathify)

function mathify() {

    this.factorial = function(num) {
        if (num === 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return num * this.factorial(num-1);
        }
    }// end of factorial
}
```

The service comes before the controller in the HTML script files. Both ctrl.num and ctrl.showfactorial aren't showing. But when I comment out showfactorial in the controller, ctrl.num is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your factorial function is exceeding the call stack size because its undefined on initialization (and you didnt have a check for that). Also, your factorial function is only running on initialization in your controller as is.

If you want the factorial result to show in the template, you should set the factorial on change, or use the factorial function in your template directly.

- This example shows using the factorial function directly in the template: http://jsfiddle.net/vq47ss7a/3/
- This example shows updating a display value in the controller on change of the input: http://jsfiddle.net/vq47ss7a/2/

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="NumCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" ng-model="ctrl.num">
        <h1>{{ctrl.num}}</h1>

        <h3>Factorial</h3>
        <p>{{ctrl.factorial( ctrl.num )}}</p>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function NumCtrl (mathify) {
  var ctrl = this;

  // get the function for use in the template
  ctrl.factorial = mathify.factorial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see this is because ctrl.num is not initialized in your controller.  This will cause your recursive factorial service method to exceed the allowable call stack.  You'll want to account for null values.

```
  this.factorial = function(num) {
      if (!num) {
        return 0;
      }
      if (num === 1) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return num * this.factorial(num - 1);
      }
    } // end of factorial
```

[I have created an example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ycTtRXKmuaI9xwABKKLS?p=preview) that should help get you started.  I used `$scope.$watch`, to update the value when the text box value changes.  You'll probably want to do something a little different though as it looks messy.

Answer (score -1):

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('NumCtrl', NumCtrl)

function NumCtrl($scope, mathify) {
//var ctrl = this;
$scope.showfactorial = mathify.factorial(ctrl.num);
}
```

Use values in the html only when they are assigned to scope of controller. In the above example the variable is declared locally but doesn't apply to scope

Comment: wrong! look up "controller as" syntax. He's doing that part correctly.